I'm using vite Vanlilla js framework ,want to connection my API but the api url port is the same as host port
I Have a problem with setting API proxy in vite.config.js
when I run NPM dev to my web and want to call API it is not using the proxy that I have defined, instead it is using my host debug URL.
I am expecting it to obey my set API target http://127.0.0.1:29985, instead it is using http://localhost:5173 as you can see in this snip from the network trace:


500 error is because the URL is wrong.

This is my JS code that calls the API
 try {
      const response = await axios.get("/api/Home/getdayoff");
      const data = response.data; 
      this.populateTable(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
    } finally {
      table.removeAttribute("loading"); 

      table.addEventListener("row-click", (e) => {
        const selectedRow = e.detail.row;
        const rowData = Array.from(selectedRow.cells).map(
          (cell) => cell.innerText
        );
        console.log(rowData);
        dialog.open = true;
        const leaveType = rowData[0];
        document.getElementById("type").value = leaveType;
      });
    }

this is my vite.config.js where I have configured the proxy
import { sync } from "glob";
import path from "path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default defineConfig({
  root: "src",
  build: {
    target: "es2022", 
    outDir: "../dist",
    emptyOutDir: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: sync("./src/**/*.html".replace(/\\/g, "/")),
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/assets"),
    },
  },
  server: {
    host: "0.0.0.0",
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://127.0.0.1:29985",  //It should proxy to this url 
        changeOrigin: true, 
        secure: false, 
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/), 
      },
    },
  },
});

How can I get the API URL at runtime to resolve to the proxy that I have configured?
My Network screeshotshot
Networkscreen

How do you know it is not working?  The screenshot of the error says it got a response (500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR).  How do you know this error is not coming from your API server running in port 29985?  The error you show alone has no evidence by itself.

BTW, the URL http://localhost:5173/api/Home/getdayoff is correct.  If you navigate to a URL that doesn't specify host, the host of the application is used, and your application is being served from http://localhost/5173, so this URL is 100% correct and expected.
